# Can not create multiple service accounts in Confluent cloud basic

Tags: confluent-platform

Starting to play around with Confluent's cloud offering and created a cluster. Was able to create my first service account successfully but now it doesn't let me create another one.

Tried to logout, login.

`ccloud service-account create "test" --description "test" -vvvv`

gives me the following output:

`UserService.CreateServiceAccount request: POST https://confluent.cloud/api/service_accounts Body:{{"user":{"organizationId":xxxx,"serviceName":"test","serviceDescription":"test","serviceAccount":true}}}
2019-10-31T13:11:44.076-0700 [DEBUG] UserService.CreateServiceAccount response: 500 Internal Server Error {"error":{"code":0,"message":"Email is already in use: pq: duplicate key value violates unique constraint \"users_email_one_active\"","nested_errors":{},"details":[],"stack":null},"user":null} request: POST https://confluent.cloud/api/service_accounts Body:{{"user":{"organizationId":xxxx,"serviceName":"test","serviceDescription":"test","serviceAccount":true}}}
Error: 1 error occurred:
    * error creating service account: Email is already in use: pq: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_email_one_active"`

Short of every application team using the same SA account, I am at a loss why it won't let me create another account

Comment: https://www.confluent.io/confluent-cloud/support/

Answer (score 0):

must have been a temporary glitch. Tried 5 minutes later and now it is working as expected